# How to collapse Javascript to definitions in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Using either VS2010 or VS2012, is there a way to collapse Javascript to definitions on an ASPX page the way c# can be collapsed in a cs page?

I've tried Microsoft Web Developer Tools, Productivity Power Tools 2012, Visual Studio Extensions and Web Essentials 2012 and can collapse each function individually, but would like to collapse all Javascript functions at once.

Comment: Not sure about "just javascript", but to collapse everything on a page, press CTRL + M, CTRL + O. If that doesn't work, select everything  (CTRL + A) and use CTRL + M, CTRL + M.

Comment: CTRL+M, CTRL+O returns "The key combination (Ctrl+M, Ctrl+O) is bound to command (Collapse to Definitions) which is not currently available.  CTRL+M, CTRL+M works, but collapses everything, so I have to drill down through the HTML tags to get back to the Javascript.  Highlighting just the JS would work, but is a bit of a hassle.